# How to avoid downloading xml in android and directly open it in url

Tags: android, xml, download

I have a url which directly downloads .pl file as xml on passing latitude and longitude within url. Now I have to first dowload it and then extract data from XML. However, i guess again and again downloading will not be a gud solution as it will make app slower. Hence, I was thinking is there a way where i can avoid downloading and make that xml directly open in browser and then parse it using SAX parser. Can I store it some variable or something similar and then can parse it?

Thanks
Astha

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the data, which means retrieve the information from a distant server. What you could achieve is to try reading the file as you download it instead of downloading (ie saving in a temp file) then reading it.

It's the same idea as watching a streaming video (youtube ...) instead of downloading then watching a video.

I have no idea though on how to read directly a stream being downloaded.

Comment: can it be directly read using SAX Parser or any python script

Comment: Or if anyone can tell me how to parse a .pl file . That would also be great